# Nintex "Server name not specified" when I Run NWAdmin tool to detach database

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, nintex-workflow

I am trying to migrate a Sharepoint 2007 Nintex workflow to Sharepoint 2010 Nintex  environment.
I used the method mentioned in the [Nintex Site](https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1180) . I have a trial version installed in the 2007 environment. Nintex clearly says that we need to use the NWAdmin.exe tool to detach the DB.

But unfortunately when I use NWAdmin.exe command it prompts with "Server name not specified" Error. This is awkward as I tried in every possible way. Can anyone help me to resolve this.

E.g.:
NWAdmin.exe –o DetachDatabase –serverName Myserver -databaseName NW2007DB

This prompts the "Server name not specified" error.